# Manually updating Windows Defender Platform Version from 4.12.x to 4.18.x

Tags: windows-defender

I manage several systems that are using Defender platform version 4.13. They will not connect to my VPN network with a platform version under 4.18. These system are not updating automatically by reaching out to Microsoft. Is there a way for me to obtain a stand-alone Defender package that can be executed to install/update over top of the existing older version?

I tried MS Catalog and run Defender Platform update packages, but nothing happens when I try to run them. I am trying to avoid re-imaging these systems. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I found that there is no way to update the Defender Platform manually that actually works. The main reason, apparently, is that Windows Defender is a huge POS. MS has an AV solution, just to have an AV solution. It doesn't mean that it's a good AV solution.

Comment: I guess a MS guy didn't like the answer I gave to my own question. I just called it as I see it. Down voted it. Pfss!